# is there a way to get all the mail id's inside workspace using directory api and service account file instead of oauth2 token?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-directory-api

I want to get the mails inside workspace mail for my google function. and updating token time to time is a problem so can this be done with directory api and service account json file??

I want to achieve this result with service account json file.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Admin SDK Directory API.
    Prints the emails and names of the first 10 users in the domain.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Admin SDK Directory API
    print('Getting the first 10 users in the domain')
    results = service.users().list(customer='my_customer', maxResults=10,
                                   orderBy='email').execute()
    users = results.get('users', [])

    if not users:
        print('No users in the domain.')
    else:
        print('Users:')
        for user in users:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(user['primaryEmail'],
                                      user['name']['fullName']))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. The code that you posted does not use a service account, it uses user authorization (OAuth Client Secrets to authorize a user identity). Are you asking how to port/transform that code so that a service account is used instead?

Comment: @JohnHanley yes you are right if you have any answer it will be very helpful/

Comment: On Stack Overflow you will find example code - I have answered a few posts with code. Google publishes example code. Search for Google Workspace Domain Wide Delegation. [details](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#optional_set_up_domain-wide_delegation_for_a_service_account) Example Python code: https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation#python

Comment: @JohnHanley I have checked these codes but I just can't get it right it requires subject as email value but I want to get all the emails I was just wondering if anyone had previously had this problem and solved it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What problem? Once you hare written code based upon the documentation, post a question with details.